# How can I clear the contents of an NSMutableAttributedString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mutable, core-foundation, nsattributedstring

I have an ivar which is alloc-inited in the init of an object:

```
attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
```

On a loop, I want to clear the contents of attString and re-use it. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
[[attString mutableString] setString:@""];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[attString release];
attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
```

Kenny's method probably quicker.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to avoid release/re-alloc to avoid memory inefficiency :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find out the methods that @kennytm mentioned above, but I did it with this:

```
[attriString setAttributedString:[NSAttributedString new]];
```

Available from mac10.0 and ios3.2 or later. Good luck for new searchers!